# how xlsxwriter worksheet write formula to calculate between columns

Tags: formula, xlsxwriter

column C =column A + column B

how to write the code in xlsxwriter, only find the code for cell
worksheet.write_formula('C1', 'B1+A1')

Comment: How would you do it in Excel?

Comment: write C1=A1+B1，then fill down in column C other cells

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

last_row = 10

for row_num in range(last_row):
    # Write some sample data.
    worksheet.write(row_num, 0, row_num)
    worksheet.write(row_num, 1, row_num * 2)

    # Create and write the formula.
    cell_row = row_num + 1
    formula =f'=A{cell_row} + B{cell_row}'
    worksheet.write_formula(row_num, 2, formula)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]